# How can I use jQuery for predefined events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

Are there any standard rules for implementing predefined events in a jQuery plugin?

For example, the special case of [**Zebra Accordion**](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Accordion) plugin (a tiny accordion plugin for jQuery) or any other plugin defines some events like below:

**Zebra Accordion Events:**

> **onClose**: Event fired after a tab is collapsed.
>
> **onOpen**: Event fired after a tab is collapsed.

In this case if I wanted to add a div with special [**Font Awesome**](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) characters (such as fa-chevron-down) after the box title when `collapsed` (Closed, collapsed state) and remove that character and replace it with a new character (like fa-chevron-up) near the box title when `expended`(opened state). I would like to finally add some functionality like [**jQuery Accordion**](https://vctrfrnndz.github.io/jquery-accordion/) to it. I've tried with the below code but it appears something is wrong:

```
$('.Zebra_Accordion').on('onOpen', function(e) {
      $(this).append( "<span class='fa fa-chevron-down'></span>" );
  });
  
$('.Zebra_Accordion').off('onClose', function(e) {
      $(this).append( "<span class='fa fa-chevron-up'></span>" );
  });
```

Comment: The code you have should work, so long as you're listening for the event on the correct element. You'll need to check the plugin documentation to ensure that - although in mosts cases you'll need to listen to the same element you define the plugin on

Comment: Many plugins don't use the standard `EventEmitter` API for events, and implement non-standard or proprietary event syntax. Check the documentation to ensure that `.on()` or `addEventListener()` is the intended way to handle custom events for this software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most jQuery plugins have an *options* object that you pass in. 
In here you can define the properties you want to set including event handlers.

The [documentation](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Accordion#events) for the zebra accordion events says for each of the events the plugin provides:

> The callback function takes 3 arguments:
>
> - the tab's position in the accordion (0 based)
> - the associated title element, as a jQuery object
> - the tab, as a jQuery object

I've just given them 3 suitable names, and used the second argument (which I arbitrarily named `hdr`).

As noted in the documentation the `hdr` argument returned is a jQuery object wrapping the `<dt>` element (at least in my example).  On this object I called the jQuery function [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the element(s) inside that `<dt>` having the `fa-chevron-*` class, and then I switch the classes on that `span` by chaining further jQuery functions.

As noted in the comments you can do it perfectly well in-line like:

```
var accordian = new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion'), {
    collapsible: true,
    onBeforeOpen: function(index, hdr, body) {
       hdr.find(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
    },
    onBeforeClose: function(index, hdr, body) {
       hdr.find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
    }
});
```

And in this particular case I would, but I wanted to illustrate what to do when the handlers have more code, in which case making them separate functions makes for better readability.

Don't forget to use **`console.log()`** a lot - it is a JavaScript developer's best friend.

To check what this Zebra Accordion was providing me I did the following first:

```
onBeforeOpen: function(index, hdr, body) {
       console.log("onBeforeOpen", index, hdr, body);
},
```

This output shows up in the browser's developer's console.

Here's my demo putting it all together:

```js
$(function() {
  
  // add default chevrons here so they only get appended once
  $(".Zebra_Accordion dt").append("<span class='chevron fa fa-chevron-down'></span>");

  // set up the according options
  var accordian = new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion'), {
    collapsible: true,
    onBeforeOpen: showCollapseChevron,
    onBeforeClose: showExpandChevron
  });
  
  function showExpandChevron(index, hdr, body) {
      hdr.find(".fa-chevron-up").removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
  }
  
  function showCollapseChevron(index, hdr, body) {
      hdr.find(".fa-chevron-down").removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
  }
  
});
```

```css
dl.Zebra_Accordion { width: 100% }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt { background: #000; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px }
dl.Zebra_Accordion dd { background: #EFEFEF; padding: 15px; margin: 1px 0 } 
dl.Zebra_Accordion dt.Zebra_Accordion_Expanded { background: #C40000 }

.chevron {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stefangabos/Zebra_Accordion/dist/zebra_accordion.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stefangabos/Zebra_Accordion/dist/zebra_accordion.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<dl class="Zebra_Accordion">
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</dt>
  <dd>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer facilisis lacinia sapien ac et. Quis hendrerit neque congue pretium iaculis justo laoreet orci elit condimentum. Eros natoque Curabitur accumsan eget quis porttitor Sed Vestibulum amet sed.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</dt>
  <dd>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer facilisis lacinia sapien ac et. Quis hendrerit neque congue pretium iaculis justo laoreet orci elit condimentum. Eros natoque Curabitur accumsan eget quis porttitor Sed Vestibulum amet sed.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</dt>
  <dd>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer facilisis lacinia sapien ac et. Quis hendrerit neque congue pretium iaculis justo laoreet orci elit condimentum. Eros natoque Curabitur accumsan eget quis porttitor Sed Vestibulum amet sed.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer</dt>
  <dd>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer facilisis lacinia sapien ac et. Quis hendrerit neque congue pretium iaculis justo laoreet orci elit condimentum. Eros natoque Curabitur accumsan eget quis porttitor Sed Vestibulum amet sed.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

External Demo https://jsfiddle.net/8wzvucgb/

Comment: Everything seems fine except adding the <span> from JavaScript - add that directly in the HTML. Other than that I would add the callback functions directly in the `options` object rather than having to come up with 2 function names.

Comment: @K Scandrett: Thank you so much for your help and reply. I appreciate you sincerely, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: @K Scandrett: Thank you so much for your help and reply. Can you help me and explain a little more about `index, hdr, body` in your approach please, Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the documentation for the zebra accordion events says the following:
"The callback function takes 3 arguments:
    the tab's position in the accordion (0 based);
     the associated title element, as a jQuery object;
     the tab, as a jQuery object"
I've just given them 3 suitable names, and used the second argument in my code.

Comment: ... that taken from the *Events* section on this page https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Accordion

Comment: @K Scandrett: Please explain a little more about the `hdr` in your solution, Thanks.

Comment: @Arash I've expanded my answer.

Comment: @K Scandrett: Thank you so much, I appreciate you greatly.

Answer (score 3):

The "Plugin Events" aren't really `events`, and won't work with on().

You can supply callbacks in the invocation that will be called when the accordion opens and closes.

Their "events" are coded in the initial invocation of the plugin:

```
var myAccordion = new $.Zebra_Accordion($('.Zebra_Accordion'),{
      onOpen:function(index,$title,$block){…},
      onClose:function(index,$title,$block){…}
});
```

It's an old-fashioned way of doing things. It's much more flexible of plugins use real events.

Answer (score 0):

What you might need: watch out for dynamically created html.
For example

```
<script>
...
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#container').append('<div class="item"> new item </div>')
})
$('#container .item').on('click', function() { ... })
...
</script>  
<input id="add" value="Add 1 item" type="button"/>  
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"> click item 1 </div>
  <div class="item"> click item 2 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the dynamically added items will not respond to the click event, because the html didn't exist yet.

---

What you do, is this:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.item', function() { ... })
```

Then, jQuery will listen to a click on #container, and then at click time it will dynamically search the .item children.

Comment: Thanks for your help and replay. I appreciate you sincerely, but what I want is to add a div with special font awesome character after box title when `collapsed` (collapsed state) and remove and replace that character  with new character as box title when it `expended` not `click` event. Thanks.